# Run js code in a separate context and access its global variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to run a third-party JavaScript file (I don't have much control over its contents) in node and access a global variable created by that file's code in its context.

There are two things I've considered:

1. Running the code in a [`vm`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) sandbox. The problem is that I don't know how to *properly* create the context, because [`vm.createContext([sandbox])`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_createcontext_sandbox) won't automatically provide basic things such as `console` or `require` or whatever to the script I want to run.

   This is a bit of a bummer, because the documentation explicitly states (emphasis mine):

   > If given a sandbox object, will "contextify" that sandbox so that it can be used in calls to vm.runInContext() or script.runInContext(). Inside scripts run as such, sandbox will be the global object, retaining all its existing properties **but also having the built-in objects and functions any standard global object has**.

   What are *"the built-in objects and functions any standard global object has"*? I'm naively assuming it's things like `console`, `process`, `require`, etc. But if so, the API doesn't work, because those are not set. I'm probably misunderstanding something here.

   ```
   var sandbox = vm.createContext({foo: 'foo'});
   var code = 'console.log(foo);';
   vm.runInContext(code, sandbox);
   ```

   Which results in:

   > evalmachine.:1
   >   console.log(foo);
   >   ^
   >   ReferenceError: console is not defined
2. Running the code in a [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). But I can't find any documentation on accessing global variables of child processes. I'm assuming the only way to communicate with a child process is by message passing, but even that seems to be from parent to child, not the other way round...

Basically, I'm stuck. Halp.

Comment: @dandavis Any type (serializable).

Comment: `child_process.exec(command[, options][, callback])`'s callback provides output to a stdOut buffer, so if your sub-process `console.logs(strJSON)`, you can get it back in the callback. the other good ways are complicated, but you can use HTTP or temp files pretty simply to accomplish some tasks... "IPC"

Comment: @dandavis I have thought about that, but the code may do its own logging and I would rather not interfere.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [advanced vm/sandbox for Node.js](https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2)

```
var VM = require('vm2').NodeVM; // https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2#nodevm

var options = {
    console: 'inherit',
    sandbox: {
        foo: 'foo'
    }
}

vm = new VM(options);

var code = `
    console.log(foo); 
    oldFoo = foo; 
    foo = Math.random();
`;

vm.run(code);

console.log(vm.context.oldFoo, vm.context.foo);
```

Comment: Looks neat and works pretty good, +1. There are edge case issues though. For example, I noticed the absence of a handler for `process.exit`.

Comment: You can use `try { vm.run } catch(e) {}` to respond to such cases?

Answer (score 0):

How about just passing the parent's `console` in a context?

```
const vm = require('vm');

var sandbox = {
  console: console
};

var context = new vm.createContext(sandbox);
var script = new vm.Script('console.log("foo")');

script.runInContext(context);
```

Comment: I have thought about this and the problem is that the code being run may require other things, like `require`, `process`, `__dirname`... I can't possibly and reliably list them all.

Comment: I would assume that you don't want to give the untrusted code access to those symbols to begin with. If you do, just pass `global` as `sandbox`.

Answer (score 0):

In this code, we can send any of the response and can access the global variable with global function and can access the whole data returning from VM Sandbox.

```
 function compiler(){
     let add = x*y
     Return (add);
 }
 compiler();
```

---

```
const vm = new NodeVM({
   sandbox: {
     Return(data) {
       console.log('Data:', data);
     },
     x : 10,=
     y : 20
   },
   require: {
     external: true,
     builtin: ["fs", "path"],
     root: "./",
     mock: {
       fs: {
         readFileSync() {
           return "Nice try!";
         }
       }
     }
   }
 });
 try {
   vm.run(req.query.code);
 } catch (error) {
   console.log("error: ", error);
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain: `Return (data) {...}` works, can you provide API? Not quite sure that this is valid JS syntax

Comment: The parameter named sandbox is just related to the declaration of the variable and the function in the sandbox environment...

Comment: You can simply name it anything you want., Its sandboxed function which we can call anytime in our code.

Comment: Which helps in doing complex task to complete by just calling it.